# Updated JasperReports jasperserver to 6.1, but can't start it

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I updated jasperreports from version 5.0 to 6.1. I ran the jasperreports update script, and it appeared to run successfully. I installed it to a new folder, following all of the update directions. I am running Tomcat and Postgresql.

However, I previously started jasperreports by running a script called:
./ctlscript.sh start

from the main Jasperreports folder in a bash shell. I am now using a different folder, and the file ctlscript.sh is not there.

Did I not update this correctly? Or am I supposed to copy that file from somewhere?

Is there some other way I should be starting jasper? What do I need to do to start the server application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked back at the installation log, and indeed there was a problem with the installation. I wound up starting fresh an ran the installation, not the upgrade, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all u refer to the jasperreports server or the jasper reports API? or for the iReport or Jasper Studio IDE's? Please rework your question... 6.1 has changed dramatically from the the 5.0 u used...so be more precise on your need.

Comment: jasperreports server. I updated it using the documentation, and put it in a new folder. I cannot start the application server I am not that familiar with apache/tomcat, etc. If that file - ctlscript.sh is not in the folder, does that mean I did not install it correctly?